# radare2 -c and -i options do not execute more than one command

Tags: radare2

All commands below do not execute `psz @ [rax]`. Why?

```
script=$(mktemp)
cat > $script << EOF
dcu 0x00404d29
psz @ [rax]
EOF
r2 -d -R input="a" -i $script exatlon_unpacked
```

```
r2 -d -R input="a" -c "dcu 0x00404d29; psz @ [rax]" exatlon_unpacked
```

```
r2 -d -R input="a" -c 'dcu 0x00404d29' -c 'psz @ [rax]' exatlon_unpacked
```